# Online courses/sources to learn chi square test of homogeneity

Tags: chi-squared-test, references

I want to study chi square test of homogeneity from any authentic source- book / website especially problems where samples are compared for more than one attribute.

> Chi square test of homogeneity is a Chi square test that determines whether two or more independent random samples are from the same or different population.

What are some relevant sources?

**Relevant background:**

I was studying examples from random  online sources before I saw this book in which a second X$^2$ has been calculated and is subtracted from the principle X$^2$ (the one we usually find). This is inconsistent to the examples I saw online.

[image]

[image]

In fact we are being taught the latter process. I'm not sure which one is correct to find the chi square of homogeneity.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "chi square homogeneity"?

Comment: @whuber Added .